# mathematics beamer problem

Tags: beamer, compiling, mathematics

I removed slides that worked, checked that they compiled properly and include here all the slides that didn't work (checked individually as well).

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usebackgroundtemplate

\begin{document}
\sffamily \bfseries

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Rational Polynomial Function}\pause
begin{itemize}
\item Let us find $\lim_{x \to \2} \frac {3x^{2}-x-10} {x^{2}-4}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Rational Polynomial Function}\pause
begin{itemize}
\item To understand limits of functions
\end{itemize}
$\lim_{x \to \2} \frac {3x^{2}-x-10} {x^{2}-4} = 2.75$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Discontinuous Function}\pause
Let us find $\lim_{x \to \0} f(x) = \[   \left\{
\begin{array}{11}
          $(2x+3) & x \leq 0$ \\
          $3(x+1) & x $>$ 0$ \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
and $\lim_{x \to \1} f(x) = \[   \left\{
\begin{array}{11}
          $(2x+3) & x \leq 0$ \\
          $3(x+1) & x $>$ 0$ \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Discontinuous Function}\pause
Let us find $\lim_{x \to \0} f(x) = \[   \left\{
\begin{array}{11}
          $(2x+3) & x \leq 0$ = 3 \\
          $3(x+1) & x $>$ 0$ \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
and $\lim_{x \to \1} f(x) = \[   \left\{
\begin{array}{11}
          $(2x+3) & x \leq 0$ = 6 \\
          $3(x+1) & x $>$ 0$ \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Assignment}\pause
\begin{itemize} [<+-|alert@+>] 
\item Find $\lim_{x \to \2} (x^{3}-2x^{2})/(x^{2}-5x+6)$
\item Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \0} \frac {sin 4x} {sin 2x}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: array entries are in math mode, remove all the `$` inside te array. Conversely the 11th slide is missing a `$` to end the mathematics

Comment: the OP's missing an `$` in the item of the 11th slide. And aren't the line breaks in the arrays after the last entry superfluous?

Comment: Where you hit return depends on what you're using to compile.  If it's the command line, you can just hit return.  With TeXworks on my Mac, there's a textfield below the message where you can enter text/hit return.

Comment: Actually the $ is there in the Latex file, just didn't copy it over here.

Comment: Generally, it helps us if you can cut your file down to the shortest file that should work but still has an error, and then copy and paste the entire file to your question.  In slide 11, you have `begin{itemize}`.  Is that really `\begin{itemize}`?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the errors:

- `begin{itemize}` -> `\begin{itemize}`
- `\2` -> `2`, same for `\1` and `\0`
- as David Carlisle already said in his comment, `array` is already in math mode, you don't need to use `$...$`.
- the alignment of the array should be `ll` not `11`
- don't nest display math environments (`\[...\]`) inside math mode
- `sin` should be `\sin`
- `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usebackgroundtemplate` are superfluous
- not a tex error as such, but `(2x+3) x≤0=6` looks misleading. Also `cases` may be better suited as an `array`

---

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usebackgroundtemplate

\begin{document}
\sffamily \bfseries

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Rational Polynomial Function}\pause
\begin{itemize}
\item Let us find $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac {3x^{2}-x-10} {x^{2}-4}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Rational Polynomial Function}\pause
\begin{itemize}
\item To understand limits of functions
\end{itemize}
$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac {3x^{2}-x-10} {x^{2}-4} = 2.75$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Discontinuous Function}\pause
Let us find \[\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
          (2x+3) & x \leq 0 \\
          3(x+1) & x > 0 \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
and \[\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
          (2x+3) & x \leq 0 \\
          3(x+1) & x > 0 \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Limit of a Discontinuous Function}\pause
Let us find \[\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
          (2x+3) & x \leq 0 = 3 \\
          3(x+1) & x > 0 \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
and \[\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
          (2x+3) & x \leq 0 = 6 \\
          3(x+1) & x > 0 \\
          \end{array}
          \right. \]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Assignment}\pause
\begin{itemize} [<+-|alert@+>] 
\item Find $\lim_{x \to 2} (x^{3}-2x^{2})/(x^{2}-5x+6)$
\item Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin 4x} {\sin 2x}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Teepeemm I added a sentence about that. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thanks to all of you who have answered and a special thanks to samcarter and Teepeemm for the detailed answer that I could compare with my errors and for the hint Teepeemm is supposed to have dropped.  The file compiled!  I am a complete novice here for Latex, no computer science background whatsoever.  I have Lamport's reference manual but it's a little daunting to learn from.  Any advice on what would be useful (Latex for dummies?)?

Comment: @VidhyaIyer see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Comment: thanks, just downloaded some of the resources, will start going through them, especially for upcoming topics: differentiaton, integration and statistics.